# Store large amounts of sensor data in SQL, optimize for query performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sensors, bigdata

I need to store sensor data from various locations (different factories with different rooms with each different sensors). Data is being downloaded in regular intervals from a device on site in the factories that collects the data transmitted from all sensors.

The sensor data looks like this:

```
collecting_device_id, sensor_id, type, value, unit, timestamp
```

`Type` could be temperature, `unit` could be degrees_celsius. `collecting_device_id` will identify the factory.

There are quite a lot of different things (==types) being measured.

I will collect around 500 million to 750 million rows and then perform analyses on them.

**Here's the question** for storing the data in a SQL database (let's say MySQL InnoDB on AWS RDS, large machine if necessary):

When considering query performance for future queries, is it better to store this data in one huge table just like it comes from the sensors? Or to distribute it across tables (tables for factories, temperatures, humidities, …, everything normalized)? Or to have a wide table with different fields for the data points?

Yes, I know, it's hard to say "better" without knowing the queries. Here's more info and a few things I have thought about:

- There's no constant data stream as data is uploaded in chunks every 2 days (a lot of writes when uploading, the rest of the time no writes at all), so I would guess that index maintenance won't be a huge issue.
- I will try to reduce the amount of data being inserted upfront (data that can easily be replicated later on, data that does not add additional information, …)
- Queries that should be performed are not defined yet (I know, designing the query makes a big difference in terms of performance). It's exploratory work (so we don't know ahead what will be asked and cannot easily pre-compute values), so one time you want to compare data points of one type in a time range to data points of another type, the other time you might want to compare rooms in factories, calculate correlations, find duplicates, etc.
- If I would have multiple tables and normalize everything the queries would need a lot of joins (which probably makes everything quite slow)
- Queries mostly need to be performed on the whole ~ 500 million rows database, rarely on separately downloaded subsets
- There will be very few users (<10), most of them will execute these "complex" queries.
- Is a SQL database a good choice at all? Would there be a big difference in terms of performance for this use case to use a NoSQL system?
- In this setup with this amount of data, will I have queries that never "come back"? (considering the query is not too stupid :-))

Comment: A vertically scaled SQL database with proper indices should be able to handle this.  I have heard that Amazon has relational databases on this order of size.  NoSQL might be cheaper from a storage point of view, but forget queries coming back at all for complex queries.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pre-optimize.  If you don't know the queries then you don't know the queries.  It is to easy to make choices now that will slow down some sub-set of queries.  When you know how the data will be queried you can optimize then -- it is easy to normalize after the fact (pull out temperature data into a related table for example.)   For now I suggest you put it all in one table.

You might consider partitioning the data by date or if you have another way that might be useful (recording device maybe?).  Often data of this size is partitioned if you have the resources.

Comment: Normally, I also say "don't pre-optimize".  However, for a project of this size, many lessons are not learned until it is "too late" to fix them.  I cover some of the lessons in my Answer.

Comment: @RickJames -- the first line of your answer mentions a requirement of  knowing what the queries are -- the whole point of this question (in my opinion) is that the asker **does not know what the queries are** and want to know how to optimize.  Other than that "small" issue your answer is excellent.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Sometimes, I recommend storing the raw incoming data in a flat file _just in case_ you later decide you needed something.  Usually such a file is much smaller than the equivalent Fact table in the db.  And one would have to write a special program to reread the data if needed.

Answer (score 1):

After you think about the queries, you will possibly realize that you don't really need all the datapoints.  Instead, max/min/avg/etc for, say, 10-minute intervals may be sufficient.  And you may want to "alarm" on "over-temp" values.  This should not involve the database, but should involve the program receiving the sensor data.

So, I recommend *not* storing all the data; instead only store summarized data.  This will greatly shrink the disk requirements.  (You *could* store the 'raw' data to a plain file in case you are worried about losing it.  It will be adequately easy to reprocess the raw file if you need to.)

If you do decide to store all the data in table(s), then I recommend these tips:

- [*High speed ingestion*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-high-speed-ingestion/) (includes tips on Normalization)
- [*Summary Tables*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/)
- [*Data Warehousing*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-techniques/)
- [*Time series partitioning*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/) (if you plan to delete 'old' data) (partitioning is painful to add later)

750M rows -- per day?  per decade?  Per month - not too much challenge.

By receiving a batch every other day, it becomes quite easy to load the batch into a temp table, do normalization, summarization, etc; then store the results in the Summary table(s) and *finally* copy to the 'Fact' table (if you choose to keep the raw data in a table).

In reading my tips, you will notice that `avg` is not summarized; instead `sum` and `count` are.  If you need standard deviation, also, keep sum-of-squares.

If you fail to include all the Summary Tables you ultimately need, it is not too difficult to re-process the Fact table (or Fact files) to populate the new Summary Table.  This is a one-time task.  After that, the summarization of each chunk should keep the table up to date.

The Fact table should be Normalized (for space); the Summary tables should be somewhat denormalized (for performance).  Exactly how much denormalization depends on size, speed, etc., and cannot be predicted at this level of discussion.

"Queries on 500M rows" -- Design the Summary tables so that all queries can be done against them, instead.  A starting rule-of-thumb:  Any Summary table should have one-tenth the number of rows as the Fact table.

Indexes...  The Fact table should have only a primary key.  (The first 100M rows will work nicely; the last 100M will run so slowly.  This is a lesson you don't want to have to learn 11 months into the project; so do pre-optimize.)  The Summary tables should have whatever indexes make sense.  This also makes querying a Summary table faster than the Fact table.  (Note:  Having a secondary index on a 500M-rows table is, itself, a non-trivial performance issue.)

NoSQL either forces you to re-invent SQL, or depends on brute-force full-table-scans.  Summary tables are the *real* solution.  In one (albeit extreme) case, I sped up a 1-hour query to 2-seconds by by using a Summary table.  So, I vote for SQL, not NoSQL.

As for whether to "pre-optimize" -- I say it is a lot easier than rebuilding a 500M-row table.  That brings up another issue:  *Start with* the minimal datasize for each field: Look at `MEDIUMINT` (3 bytes), `UNSIGNED` (an extra bit), `CHARACTER SET ascii` (utf8 or utf8mb4) only for columns that need it), `NOT NULL` (`NULL` costs a bit), etc.

Sure, it is possible to have 'queries that never come back'.  This one 'never comes back, even with only 100 rows in `a`:  `SELECT * FROM a JOIN a JOIN a JOIN a JOIN a`.  The resultset has 10 billion rows.